# Desktop icons move around on boot

Tags: unity, icons, desktop-icons

When I boot ubuntu 11.10 sometimes on boot the desktop icons move places!

For example, I have several icons placed near the bottom of the screen. When I boot these icons have moved up the screen about 3 rows.

Can anyone tell me why? and How to stop this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the relevant bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/886667 but there's been nothing new for over a month.

I have the problem too.

Comment: And this question is similar to [Organize Desktop by Name sometimes doesn't retain order after a restart](http://askubuntu.com/questions/98318/organize-desktop-by-name-sometimes-doesnt-retain-order-after-a-restart) and two others.

Comment: Non has a workaround, a nastry script to execute at startup or any trick?

Answer (score 0):

This has now stopped as I've upgraded to 12.04LTS.

Comment: Dear Rick & Eric - I know this doesn't provide an answer to the question I originally asked - but as I've upgraded to 12.04LTS there's no way of me finding out if any solutions offered by anyone will work or not because I can't test it!!! So, why have both of you put your comments down? I don't understand what I'm supposed to do to - if you could clarify for me and I'll try my best.